# passing string value to a struct variable

Tags: arrays, c, struct, c-strings

I'm working on an assignment for my C class, and trying to pass a string value into a struct variable using a function, and then using another function to get the string value, then finally printing the string. When I try using strcpy() it's not passing the string into the variable, and when printing it's just an empty string.
Here's what I'm trying:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    typedef struct MyStruct_struct {
        char myString[20];
    } MyStruct;

    MyStruct SetString(char* userString, MyStruct test) {
        strcpy(test.myString, userString);
        return test;
    }

    void GetString(char* userString, MyStruct test) {
        strcpy(test.myString, userString);
    }

    int main() {
        MyStruct newStruct;
        newStruct = SetString("hello", newStruct);
        char newString[20];

        GetString(newString, newStruct);

        printf("%s\n", newString);

        return 0;
```

Comment: Your `GetString` and `SetString` both copy in the same direction (into the struct).

Comment: this doesn't compile, that should be `stdio.h`, and `void` at least. Please provide the _exact_ code you're running with, or who knows if the advice you receive is even relevant.

Comment: You keep editing your code to further versions that don't compile and that you obviously haven't tested. Test your code before posting it here!

Comment: @interjay I'm working in an interactive textbook for this class that doesn't work like a regular IDE, so I'm not able to copy my exact code and test it, sorry, I am also new to this language.

Comment: You might as well learn early that `strcpy()` is problematic because it can overflow a buffer. `strncpy()` can underflow and not terminate properly - it's fine if you always set the last buffer byte to '\0' in the line after, but it's easy to forget. `strlcpy()` is best if it's available, but it's not standard, so `snprintf()` or a variant is probably what you should use.

Comment: @JohnBayko at this point in my class we have only learned strcpy() so that is what I'm supposed to use for this assignment

Comment: `strcpy` **is** the function that does this; no need to copy variables in `SetString`. `GetString` is also kind of redundant, _eg_ `static char *GetString(const struct MyStruct_struct *test) { return test->myString; }...printf("%s\n", GetString(&newStruct))` could be just `...printf("%s\n", newStruct.myString)`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly you need to pass the address/reference of newStruct to your function. The way you are doing it creates a copy of the structure in stack, when the function is called. It copies the string 'hello' and exits. The address to which the string was copied on stack is no longer valid upon exiting.
2. In GetString you would want to do the other way around copy from myString into userString strcpy(test.myString, userString);

See the code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct MyStruct_struct {
    char myString[20];
} MyStruct;

void SetString(char* userString, MyStruct *test) {
    strcpy(test->myString, userString);
}

void GetString(char* userString, MyStruct *test) {
    strcpy(userString, test->myString);
}

int main() {
    MyStruct newStruct;
    SetString("hello", &newStruct);
    char newString[20];

    GetString(newString, &newStruct);

    printf("%s\n", newString);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: #1 is a good idea, yet passing the `struct` in to and from the function is not the issue.  #2 is.

Comment: "The address to which the string was copied on stack is no longer valid upon exiting." the string is already copied inside the structure, we don't care about loosing it at that point.

Comment: Passing by reference isn't a simple concept for beginners, I think it's better to let them understand the basics of the language first.